# Do you need to solder the center point in this type of BGA chip?

Tags: soldering

I have the following chip. I'm not sure if its called a BGA chip or not. I need this chip replaced and I'm able to remove it using a hot air station, but I would like to know if I require soldering the center pad that is underneath the chip. Is this point usually used for important data that needs to be read or is just mainly for securing the chip with glue?

[image]

Comment: That's not a BGA, it's a QFN. The datasheet will most likely tell you if the center pad needs to be soldered (either for electrical contact or for heat dissipation).

Comment: For comparison, a [BGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_grid_array)(Ball Grid Array) chip has a grid of typically circular pads under it, and the connection to the PCB is done with pre-made balls of solder instad of solder paste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This style of package is [QFN (Quad Flat No-leads package)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quad_Flat_No-leads_package).  The specific instructions about connecting the pad would be found in the datasheet.  ([@brhans have mentioned this already.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/263196/do-you-need-to-solder-the-center-point-in-this-type-of-bga-chip#comment588813_263196))

The central pad is usually connected to GND, although GND is sometimes also wired to one of the pins on the periphery.

The pad may also also serve for heat sinking the IC to the PCB.  For some ICs the heat sinking aspect is important (power ICs, for example).  For other ICs, it's not important.  Solder provides a better thermal path than lack thereof.